# convexity proof of a function including ln and sums

Tags: convex-analysis

$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i\ln x_i-\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i\right)\ln\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i\right)\rightarrow R_{++}^n$$

How can I prove this is convex on $R_{++}^n$? I tried using the Hessian and couldn't prove it. There is a solution using the gradient and Jensen but very long and complicated.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math Stack Exchange. To get the best answers at your level, learn most, and prevent people form giving hints, please include your attempt – what have you tried using Hessian? You can edit your post to include this.

Comment: For instance, why don't you share the Hessian with us. Others might see the crucian final step of proving positive semidefiniteness.

Comment: Also asked here. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281612/convexity-proof-of-a-function-including-ln-and-sums#comment2602514_1281612

Answer (score 5):

Taking the Hessian gives
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j\partial x_k}f(x)
=\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\frac1{x_1}&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&\frac1{x_2}&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&\frac1{x_3}&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&\frac1{x_n}
\end{bmatrix}}^{\small\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j\partial x_k}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\log(x_i)}
-\overbrace{\frac1{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&\cdots&1\\
1&1&1&\cdots&1\\
1&1&1&\cdots&1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&1&1&\cdots&1
\end{bmatrix}\vphantom{\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{x_1}\\\frac1{x_1}\\\frac1{x_1}\\\vdots\\\frac1{x_1}\end{bmatrix}}}^{\small\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j\partial x_k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)\log\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)}
$$
Thus, by [Hölder's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality),
$$
\begin{align}
u^T\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j\partial x_k}f(x)u
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{u_i^2}{x_i}
-\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^nu_i\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}\\
&=\frac1{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{u_i^2}{x_i}-\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^nu_i\right)^2\right)\\
&\ge0
\end{align}
$$
The [Hessian Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) is [positive semi-definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix), so $f$ is convex.

Comment: how is this holders inequality? what's p and what's q?

Comment: hm - p=q=2 , but consider $x = (\sqrt x_1....), u = (\sqrt u_1....)$

Comment: So it's Cauchy-Schwarz, which is a special case ($p=q=2$) of Hölder:$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{u_i^2}{x_i}\ge\left(\sum_{i=1}^nu_i\right)^2$$

Comment: @robjohn I've got this problem too and can you solve this by showing the first sum is sum on convex and the second one is affine change where $(\sum x_i)(\ln(\sum x_i)=z\ln(z)$ but i got stcuk here

Comment: @ronkurman: I am not sure what inequality you are trying to show.

Comment: @robjohn, can you please explain the how did you expand $u^T \nabla f u$? I don't understand the first transition (with $\left( \sum{u_i} \right)^2$). I got the following: $$u^T  \nabla f u=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{u_i^2}{x_i}}-\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}} \sum_{i \neq j}{u_i u_j}$$

Comment: @Dennis: the only difference between your result and mine is that yours does not include the terms with $i=j$ in the second sum. Why would those terms not be there?

Comment: @robjohn, when I tried again to do the multiplication matix-wise I got your result. But as far as I know, expressing quadratic form as summation equals $$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^nx_ia_{ij}x_j$$ If we want to split the sum into two sums, where one is for $i=j$ and the second one is for $i \neq j$, shouldn't it be as I suggested?

Comment: I don't want to split the sum like that.