# How to prove $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum x_i\ln x_i - (\sum x_i )\ln(\sum x_i)$ is convex on R++

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

How can i prove $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum x_i\ln x_i - (\sum x_i )\ln(\sum x_i)$ is convex on R++

Comment: Please reproduce your question within the body of the question. There are many reasons this is a good practice, but for one example note that LaTeX isn't rendered properly in titles on the android app.

Comment: Can you add what you have tried?

Comment: I am thinking it has something to do with the Jensen inequality,

Comment: Try taking partial derivatives and prove $\left(\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\right)$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite.

Comment: How odd that this was posted twice in one day. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281612/convexity-proof-of-a-function-including-ln-and-sums#comment2602514_1281612

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate.

Comment: @quid: The other question now has an answer, so I closed this for being a duplicate.